# How can i solve the problem Violation d'index unique ou clé primaire in my project jhipster quarkus

Tags: jhipster, quarkus, jhipster-blueprint

**I was trying to develop a Jhipster Quarkus app with two entities, Product and Category. I've generated the app but when I try to add a category I get the issue mentioned**

**my jdl file :**

`entity Product {
designation String
prix Double
quantity Integer
}

entity Category {
libelle String
}

relationship ManyToOne
Product{Category(libelle)} to Category
}`

**Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Violation d'index unique ou clé primaire: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.CATEGORY(ID) ( /* key:1 / CAST(1 AS BIGINT), 'Table')"
Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.CATEGORY(ID) ( / key:1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT), 'Table')"; SQL**

Comment: Could you update question with stacktrace and entities so we can help ?

Comment: Well check the contents of your table in h2 console, it si probably not empty and contains already a row with key 1 that was created by CSV file loaded by Liquibase. CHeck also the CSV file